# Multi-deformed numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, quantum-groups

The following deformations of usual numbers are well-known:
$$
[n]_q=\frac{q^n-q^{-n}}{q-q^{-1}},
$$
and 
$$
[n]_{pq}=\frac{p^n-q^{-n}}{p-q^{-1}}.
$$

**Question.** Are there any meaningful further deformations 
$[n]_{pqr...}?$

Comment: What's your source for this definition of $[n]_q$? What I'm familiar with [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog#%22Classical%22_q-theory) $[n]_q=\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$, i.e. $[n]_q^\text{Leox}=q^{1-n}[n]_{q^2}^\text{Ernst}$ viz. Eq. (2.1) [here](http://www.solnaschack.org/ernst/ernst_10-4cor.pdf).

Comment: see for example the paper QUANTUM GROUPS AND THEIR APPLICATIONS IN NUCLEAR PHYSICS  at arxiv

Comment: In other words, Eqs. (2.1) & (2.11) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-th/9909003.pdf). Thanks! It looks a good read.

Comment: Writing $q=e^\eta$ shows that $[n]_q$ is in some sense trigonometric. There are also 'elliptic deformations' of the integers, see e.g. (3.7) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01720 . These are good (cf Somos' answer) in that there are again versions of the binomial theorem etc, and are related to elliptic quantum groups.

Comment: You might, or might not get something out of the examples displayed [here](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/paradig.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to find a good meaning for "deformation" of the integers. Your second definition
$$ [n]_{pq}=\frac{p^n-q^{-n}}{p-q^{-1}} \tag{1}$$
is essentially the same as the definition of the [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) function
$$ U_n(P,Q) := \frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta} \tag{2}$$
where $\ \alpha,\beta\ $ are the roots of $\ x^2-Px+Q = 0.\ $ 
An essential property of these deformed integers is that they become integers in some suitable limit. For example, for the Lucas sequence
$$  \lim_{\beta\to\alpha} \frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta} =
   n\alpha^{n-1} = n(P/2)^{n-1} \tag{3}$$ and so when $\ P=2\ $ and
$\ Q=1\ $ we get the definition
$\ U_n(2,1) := n,\ $ as it should be.

What is beyond Lucas sequences? Lucas himself was searching for this
in his research into primality testing as described in *Edouard Lucas and Primality Testing* by Hugh C. Williams. So we are looking for sequences which satisfy recursion relations and which depend on parameters that reduce to the integers in some limiting case.

One direction would be to use classical special functions to define the sequence. For example,
$$ T_n = T_n(x) := \tan(n\ x)/x \tag{4} $$
where $\ T_n(x) \to n\ $ as $\ x \to 0.\ $ One of many recursions it satisfies is
$$ T_{n+1}(T_1 + 2T_{n-1} - T_n) = (T_1 + T_n)T_{n-1}. \tag{5} $$
Other special functions include the Jacobi $\ sn\ $ and $\ \theta\ $
functions, the
Weierstrass $\ \sigma\ $ function and a few others. My own efforts in this direction are a part of my [collection of special algebraic identities](http://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/ident04.html).

A related special case is [Elliptic divisibilty sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_divisibility_sequence) which satisfy many recurrence relations and naturally come from multiples of points on elliptic curves. My own efforts in this direction are partly desribed
in my [WXYZ project](http://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/wxyz.html) files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen one, but let's cook something up. If you don't mind, I'll add a comma betwen the two suffixes in the second deformation, so $pq$ doesn't look like a $1$-index product.

Since $[n]_{p,\,q}=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{(n-1)/2}[n/2]_{p/q}$ expresses a double deformation in terms of a single deformation, one option is to define$$[n]_{p,\,q,\,r}:=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{(n-1)/2}[n/2]_{p/q,\,r}=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{(n-1)/2}\left(\frac{p}{qr}\right)^{(n/2-1)/2}[n/4]_{p/(qr)}$$etc., i.e. $$[n]_{p_1,\,\cdots,\,p_j}=\left(\prod_{k=2}^j\left(\frac{p_1}{\prod_{l=2}^k P_l}\right)^{(n/2^{k-2}-1)/2}\right)[n/2^{j-1}]_{p_1/\prod_{k\ge 2}p_k}.$$I'll leave you to invent an alternative in which $[n]_{p,\,q,\,r}:=\left(\frac{q}{r}\right)^{(n-1)/2}[n/2]_{p,\,q/r}$ etc. instead.

Comment: Thank you......